# (how do I)Azure data Factory to (on prem) mysql DB connection using cert

Tags: mysql, azure-data-factory

We need to pull data from a client on prem DB, they require us to use SSL+ their cert when connecting.

The only issue I'm having is: I have no idea where to "import" the PEM file for their certs in data factory. I know that I should use:"UseSystemTrustStore=<0/1>;" in my connection string when setting up the Data factory connection but can't understand where I should put the cert files.

PS. running DFv2 
also: my appologies for bad english It's not my first language.

-Duck

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with on-premises data, usually you will want to use a [self-hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime).  The self-hosted integration runtime will handle the connection issues.

You can store your certificates in Azure Key Vault, and then reference the certificate , as explained in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/store-credentials-in-key-vault)

Comment: It does, we have one deployed. Using normal sql auth it works like a charm. The problem comes in when the SQL connection needs a client certificate to complete the connection. Thanks for the reply none the less.

Comment: Linking this to in-progress [MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cfafd67d-50ff-4cad-b817-dc303f6cd3de/need-to-connect-to-on-premise-mysql-using-sql-auth-certificate-and-key?forum=AzureDataFactory).